# SoapUI transfer property to Endpoint

Tags: rest, get, soapui

I'm using SoapUI to call a web service.

I have two call, one returns an id to me, the second one use this id to make his request.

This is how the second call looks like:

```
https://example.com/something/{id}
```

With the property transfer, I have no problem retrieving the id from the first call. But when I try to add it to my endpoint (Property transfer -> Target: XXX, Property: Endpoint), the whole Endpoint is replaced by {id}.

I know I probably need to write something on the "box" belove the "Target" line, but I have no idea what.

---

I already tried to google it, but I seem to only found answers which are using a Groovy script and this sounds *way* too complicated for what I want to do. Surely, there is an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Properties teststep to your testcase.

Add a parameter to the Properties teststep named "id"

Change your property transfer teststep to target id inside Properties

Now open your second call, and change the value of the id parameter to ${Properties#id} and the id from your Properties teststep should be used as the value.

Your REST Request teststep should look something like this.
[image: Screendump showing the REST Request teststep]

The "/value" at the top right, is there because I actually typed in "value" in the Properties teststep in the id parameter

If you are having problems getting your request to look something like that, try creating a new REST Request teststep, and then choose to create a new Rest request, and then type in something like

```
http://example.com/{id}
```

...when prompted for the endpoint.

Comment: This seems to work (even though I stubble in another problem). Could I suggest that you edit your post to add how my URL should now look like? ( https://example.com/something/${Data_from_response#id} )

Comment: Done. I hope that helps. :)